# Perl regex finding string containing keywords in order

Tags: regex, perl

I am learning Perl. I want to find all occurences of 3 keywords in this **order**: `keyword1`, `keyword2` and `keyword3`  in a text. `keyword1` and `keyword3` are optional. It can have up to 6 words between keywords. This is the code in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$reg="(keyword1)*\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}?(keyword2)\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}?(keyword3)*";
$content="some words before keyword1 optional word here then keyword2 again optional words then keyword3 others words after.";
while ($content=~m/$reg/g) {
    print "$&\n";
}
```

I want to extract only the substring `keyword1 optional word here then keyword2 again optional words then keyword3` but I got `keyword2`. Thank you.

Comment: Your spec is far from clear. Do you have an actual use case or is this just a random exercise?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`! It should catch a problem: `\w` and `\W` in a double-quoted string literal. Escape the slash or switch to using `qr//`.

Comment: `qr/\b (?: k1 \W+ (?: \w+ \W+ ){0,6}? )? k2 (?: \W+ (?: \w+ \W+ ){0,6}? k3 )? \b/x`

Comment: @ikegami This works perfectly!!!. Thank you very very very much.

Comment: @melpomene, this is an exercise. Thank for the comment.

Comment: You can accept the answer and vote for champs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `"\w"` produces the string `w`, and `"\W"` produces the string `W`.

```
$ perl -wE'say "\w\W"'
Unrecognized escape \w passed through at -e line 1.
Unrecognized escape \W passed through at -e line 1.
wW
```

You need to escape the backslash (`"\\W"`) or use `qr//` (`qr/\W/`).

---

I'm pretty sure there are other problems with the pattern. I'm going to start from scratch.

Assumes `k1` and `k3` are both independently optional, you want:

```
qr/
    (?: \b k1 \W+
        (?: \w+ \W+ ){0,6}?
    )?

    \b k2 \b

    (?: 
        (?: \W+ \w+ ){0,6}?
        \W+ k3 \b
    )?
/x
```

The word boundaries (`\b`) are there to ensure that we don't match `abck2def` or `abck1 k2 k3def`.

---

The above is inefficient.

Take for example the following regex pattern:

```
(?: x y )? x z
```

It can match the following strings:

```
xyxz
xz
```

Notice how both start with `x`? That means a better pattern (i.e. one that performs less backtracking) would be

```
x (?: y x )? z
```

There are a couple of instances of this anti-pattern in the above answer. So let's refactor.

```
qr/
    \b
    (?: k1 \W+ (?: \w+ \W+ ){0,6}? \b )?
    k2 \b
    (?: \W+ (?: \w+ \W+ ){0,6}? k3 \b  )?
/x
```

Now we have something efficient.

---

In the above pattern, notice that the second `\b` is redundant. So let's get rid of it.

If we add a `\b` to the very end, the third and fourth `\b` become redundant.

After applying those simplifications, we get:

```
qr/
    \b
    (?: k1 \W+ (?: \w+ \W+ ){0,6}? )?
    k2
    (?: \W+ (?: \w+ \W+ ){0,6}? k3 )?
    \b
/x
```

---

Personally, I strongly dislike the non-greediness modifier as anything but a optimization. Furthermore, the use of two of them is normally a giant red flag that there is a bug in the pattern. For example, the pattern can match `k1 k1 k2`, but that may not be desirable.

To eliminate them, we need to ensure the first `\w+` doesn't match `k1` or `k2`. This can be achieved by replacing

```
\b \w+ \b
```

with

```
(?! \b k1 \b ) (?! \b k2 \b ) \b \w+ \b
```

Again, we factor out common prefixes to get:

```
\b (?! (?: k2 | k3 ) \b ) \w+ \b
```

Similarly, we need to ensure that the second `\w+` doesn't match `k2` or `k3`.

With these changes, we get:

```
qr/
    \b
    (?: k1 \W+ (?: (?! (?: k1 | k2 ) \b ) \w+ \W+ ){0,6} )?
    k2
    (?: \W+ (?: (?! (?: k2 | k3 ) \b ) \w+ \W+ ){0,6} k3 )?
    \b
/x
```

---

Complicated? yes. A better solution might start by breaking down the stream into word and non-word tokens. The advantage of this is that we don't have to worry about boundaries anymore.

```
my @tokens = split(/(\W+)/, $content, -1);
```

Then, the array is checked for the pattern. Since the regex engine is particular adept at doing this, we can leverage it as follows:

```
my $tokens =
   join '',
      map {
         ($_ % 2) ? "W"
         : $words[$_] eq "k1" ? 1
         : $words[$_] eq "k2" ? 2
         : $words[$_] eq "k3" ? 3
         : "w"                      # Non-key word
      }
         0..$#tokens;

while ($tokens =~ /(?: 1 W (?: w W ){0,6} )? 2 (?: W (?: w W ){0,6} 3 )?/xg) {
   say join('', @tokens[ $-[0] .. $+[0] - 1 ]);
}
```

Given the that `@tokens` will always be of the form word, non-word, word, non-word, etc, we can also use the following:

```
my $words =
   join '',
      map {
         ($_ % 2) ? ""              # We just want to look at the words
         : $words[$_] eq "k1" ? 1
         : $words[$_] eq "k2" ? 2
         : $words[$_] eq "k3" ? 3
         : "w"                      # Non-key word
      }
         0..$#tokens;

while ($words =~ /(?: 1 w{0,6} )? 2 (?: w{0,6} 3 )?/xg) {
   say join('', @tokens[ $-[0] * 2 .. ( $+[0] - 1 ) * 2 ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you again for the detailed answer!